# Android getActionBar().setTitle does not work

Tags: android, android-actionbar

ActionBar - setTitle seems to not to be called. All other things I'm doing with ActionBar (like HomeIsUp and so on) are going well, but setTitle - not.

Here is the code of a simple activity:

```
public class GuidelineDetails extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    String guideline_name;
    String guideline_attachment;

    public static TextView tv_title;
    public static TextView tv_intro;
    public static TextView tv_test;
    public static WebView webview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.guideline_detail);
        getActionBar().setTitle("Privet");
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.listbullet);

///// some code
}
}
```

**Why does it not set the title?**

in manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".GuidelineDetails"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="Guideline"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
        </activity>
```

in layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/guideline_title"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="1dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="1dp"
                    android:paddingTop="35dp"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.16"
        android:orientation="vertical" >     

         <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

          <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webviewD"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>

        </TableRow>



    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Well what title you want to set "Guideline" or "Privet" ? Accordingly set it **either** in manifest or via code in `onCreate` as you are doing. So decide and do one

Comment: @ShobhitPuri deleted statement android:label="Guideline" but still does not work :(

Comment: Yes as you have `setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)`. Try making it true.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

because of

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

change it to

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Not working for me:         getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.action_bar_title);

Comment: @YuvalLevy did you ever find a solution to your problem? setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true) is also not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to set subTitle? Because in some cases if device screen is small in ActionBar you can see only the ActionBar icon. Try this.getActionBar().setTitle("Privet");  Hope this will help you!

Comment: 1) your code has nothing different from my. 2) tried setSubitle - does not work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the Manifest file over rules it. I was having same issue with my icon, so I just had to change it in manifest file (`android:label="Guideline"`), or try not setting a label in Manifest if you have to set it grammatically.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but it did not help :( deleted this from manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Try to extend ActionBarActivity instead of Activity

Answer (score 0):

in the manifest:

```
    <activity android:name=".MessagingActivity"
        android:label="MessagingActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
```

And in the Activity:

```
public class MessagingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView profileImage;
private TextView username;
private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
private DatabaseReference referense;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_messaging);
    Toolbar toolbarLcl = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbarLcl );
    ActionBar mActionBarLcl = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBarLcl.setTitle("username");
    mActionBarLcl.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    toolbarLcl .setNavigationOnClickListener(v->{
        finish();
    });.....
```

and the  xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>                                                            <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MessagingActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    >

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_messaging" />


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `themes.xml` file.
In the `<Style />` element, you can see:

```
(Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar)
```

So you have to change it like this:

```
(Theme.Material13.Light)
```

Comment: first of all you have to set Action bar Then your getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title); Wil Work.